# agregar clases diferentes en un foreach

Tags: jquery

Tengo este código que me rellena un arregloe el cual despliega dos imagenes.

```
for (img of transactionImages) {
    let image = document.createElement("img");
    //$(image).addClass("box_imgpeque");
    $(image).attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + img);   
    diImages.append(image);
}
```

Necesito agregarla una clase diferente a cada imagen.

```
for (img of transactionImages) {
    let image = document.createElement("img");


    $(image).attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + img);

    $("#diImages img").addClass("imagen1");

    if($("#diImages img").hasClass("imagen1")){
        $("#diImages img").addClass("imagen2");
    } else {
        $("#diImages img").addClass("imagen1");     
    }
}
```

intente varias cosas, en este ultimo lo que hace agrega las clases, pero al primer elemento le agrega las dos

¿Existe alguna forma en que un ciclo for le agrega una clase a cada elemento diferente?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera:

async function ShowTransactionImages(transactionImages) {
    var numero = 0;
    diImages.empty();

```
for (img of transactionImages) {
    let image = document.createElement("img");


    $(image).attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + img).addClass("box_imgpeque" + numero).addClass("imageresource" + numero);

    diImages.append(image); 

    numero++;

}


    $(".box_imgpeque0").on("click", function () {

        $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('.imageresource0').attr('src')); // here asign the image to the modal when the user click the enlarge link
        $('#imagemodal').modal('show'); 
    });

    $(".box_imgpeque1").on("click", function () {

        $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('.imageresource1').attr('src')); // here asign the image to the modal when the user click the enlarge link
        $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
    });
```

}

Habia que agregar los atributos en el arreglo para que no se perdieran, ni los agregara doble.

$(image).attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + img).addClass("box_imgpeque" + numero).addClass("imageresource" + numero);

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar un contador asi:

```
let x = 1;
for (img of transactionImages) {
  let image = document.createElement("img");

  //$(image).addClass("box_imgpeque");
  $(image).attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + img);

  $(image).addClass("imagen" + x);
  x++;
}
```